# MapKit, Dropping pin on one location with button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Trying to learn how to have a pin drop at a users location when they push a button on screen.  Do I need to use Mkannotation, also I want this pin to disappear when they drop a new pin in the future.  This is the code I have in controller.h.  Also the longitude and latitude are just for example.

thanks

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
zoomLocation.longitude = -76.580806;

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation,             
0.1*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.1*METERS_PER_MILE);  

[_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What is the question? Have you read any tutorials or class documentation? You should also call super first in viewWillAppear...

Answer (score 1):

While I think this is discussed in some detail in the [Adding Annotations to a Map](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW33) section of the *Location Awareness Programming Guide,* I have a few observations:

You ask "do I need to use `MKAnnotation`?" Yes and no.

- Yes, all annotations should conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. As that guide describes, if you can create your own annotation subclass, you'd want it explicitly declare it to conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol.
- But, no, you don't have to always create your own annotation class that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. You can also use a predefined annotation class, `MKPointAnnotation` (which, itself, already conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol), such as:

  ```
  MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
  annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.281516, -76.580806);
  annotation.title = @"Lens Crafters";
  annotation.subtitle = @"2400 Boston St.";
  [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
  ```

If you want the old annotation to disappear when you drop a new one on your map, you just (a) keep a reference to the old annotation; (b) when adding a new annotation, remove the old one (if you have an old one); and then (c) add your new annotation.

Thus you might have defined some class property for your annotation:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MKAnnotation> annotation;
```

(Two side observations: First, whether you use `weak` or `strong` is up to you and your app design. By saying `weak`, I'm saying that when the annotation is removed from the map, I'm happy to have the `annotation` released. Maybe you want it retained until you explicitly `nil` this property, in which case you'd make this property `strong`. That's entirely up to you and the goals of your app. Second, I use the type `id<MKAnnotation>` (i.e. "an object that conforms to `MKAnnotation`") which makes this more flexible. If you later replace `MKPointAnnotation` with your own custom annotation class, this property will still work. But if you want to explicitly define this `annotation` property to be a `MKPointAnnotation` to match your annotation adding routine, that's fine, too.)

Anyway, now that you have this property, you can now write a method to add an annotation to your map (which removes the old one):

```
- (void)addAnnotationAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
                            title:(NSString *)title
                         subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    if (self.annotation)
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.annotation];

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
    annotation.title = title;
    annotation.subtitle = subtitle;

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    self.annotation = annotation;
}
```